# Cannot change tex4ht.env

Tags: tex4ht

I have installed the latest version of WinEdt v7 and MiKTeX (october 2012). When I run `latex2html` and `tex4ht` is called the `tex4ht.env` file is everytime overwritten with the default settings. Even if I edit it in the `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\base\win32` folder the version saved in my LaTex source folder looks like the original and if I modify that, it is also rewritten. Where does it come from?

I need to change the resolution `dvi2png` creates, and that is, as far as I understand done by changing the `tex4ht.env` file - but again - when I change it, it changes back

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option for `tex4ht` that allows specifying the pixel density of the generated images: `graphics-300` would create 300-dpi bitmaps.

```
htlatex input "html, graphics-300"
```

Does this work for you?

This switch (and many other) are documented in [this blog entry](http://www.cvr.cc/tex4ht-options/).

Please DO NOT change files that live in `C:\Program Files`.